# Restart WingIDE debugger after file change

Tags: python, django, wing-ide

I'm using django python with wingIDE and every time I make a change I have to restart the debugger and refresh the page. Most of the time I forget to restart my debugger and it takes a second to figure out why my web page didn't change. I was wondering if anyone new any easy way to make the debugger restart every time a file is saved or changed. I believe I've scene this feature somewhere else, I just can't seem to find it for wing. I hope there is just a preference I'm missing or something simple like that.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default configuration of the debugger launches Django from Wing IDE and disables auto-reload, so the restart button in Wing must be pressed before changes take effect in the debug process. To launch from outside the IDE and to handle auto-reload automatically see Debugging with Auto-Reload at the end of http://wingware.com/doc/howtos/django